# MySQL group joins with null value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to create a MySQL query which will return the number of customers that are related to a user that were created in a date range. I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`customer`.`user_id`) as `count`, `user`.`first_name`,  `user`.`last_name`
FROM (`user`) 
LEFT JOIN `customer` ON `user`.`id` = `customer`.`user_id`
WHERE `customer`.`date_created` >= '2014-03-27 23:41:28' AND `customer`.`date_created` <= '2014-04-04 00:41:28'
GROUP BY `customer`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY `count`
LIMIT 5
```

If I remove the where clause then I get the results I would expect including null values:

```
count   first_name   last_name
0       Name         Name
1       Name         Name
3       Name         Name
10      Name         Name
```

The problem is that when I introduce the where clause I don't get the rows returned that have no value for count. Can anyone help?

Comment: user 1<-->N customer?

Answer (score 2):

Move your where condition to `ON()` clause so it will filter the results from right table not all result set ,and will produce the 0 count for the unmatched results from left table

```
SELECT COUNT(`customer`.`user_id`) as `count`, 
`user`.`first_name`, 
 `user`.`last_name`
FROM `user` 
LEFT JOIN `customer` ON (
`user`.`id` = `customer`.`user_id`
AND `customer`.`date_created` >= '2014-03-27 23:41:28'
 AND `customer`.`date_created` <= '2014-04-04 00:41:28')
GROUP BY `user`.`id` 
ORDER BY `count`
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems closer now. I'm getting some odd results when taking off the limit though. It doesn't return all the users. I can't seem to see any reason why with the data.

Comment: I've tested this with 11 users and it only ever returns one user with zero data. If you give one of the users a customer the they start to appear but you never seem to get more than one user with a zero number of customers.

Comment: @user2486399 can you provide [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example your tables with sample dataset it would be easier to identify the problem

Comment: The problem is caused by the wrong `GROUP BY` clause. Grouping on a  `LEFT JOIN`'d column will result in all rows with no match in the right table (i.e. with `NULL` values for the right table) being grouped in the same group. Replace with `GROUP BY user.id`.

Comment: @RandomSeed i havn't realized the group by clause thanks for this point